# how to add border radius to google maps in flutter?

Tags: google-maps, flutter, flutter-layout

[image]

I added a google map widget into a container with a border radius but google maps corners not rounded .

```js
Container(
            height: 100,
            width: double.infinity,
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 30, right: 30),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
              border: Border.all(
                style: BorderStyle.solid,
              ),
            ),
            child: GoogleMap(),)
```

Answer (score 54, accepted):

probably an expensive solution but you could use `ClipRRect`. Something like this:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
          topLeft: Radius.circular(30),
          topRight: Radius.circular(30),
          bottomRight: Radius.circular(30),
          bottomLeft: Radius.circular(30),
        ),
        child: Align(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
          heightFactor: 0.3,
          widthFactor: 2.5,
          child: GoogleMap(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: if you're happy with the answer you should mark it correct and up vote it,,thanks

Comment: Hmm doing this doesn't seem to work for me. I am still left with a rectangular google maps

Comment: It seems that there are currently a bug on IOS that don't allow clipping. See the following reported [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/30117)

Comment: any other way than Clipping as it cost GPU

Answer (score 3):

Keep in mind that the `google_maps_flutter` plugin is only a developer preview.  I'm sure a lot more work will be added to this before they release version 1.0.  So don't stress too much about missing features.  File tickets. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
Padding(
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.sp),
  child: SizedBox(
    width: 100.w,
    height: 30.h,
    child: ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(30)),
      child: GoogleMap(),
    ),
  )
),
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**